# How to replace elements in one list with elements of another?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble replacing the elements of my list `gridCurrent` with those of `gridprevious` (this is for the Game of Life). I've listed my entire code below but the only part that I need help with is the function `gridUpdate` I want to call my function `countLiveNeighbors` and then Loop over grid rows, and for each row, loop over columns.

```
gridPrevious = []
gridCurrent = []

# This function is fine

def gridToString( grid ): 

    mystr = ''
    for row in grid:
         for cell in row:
             if cell == 0:
                 mystr += "+"
             else:
                 mystr += '+O'[cell]
         mystr += '\n'
    return mystr
    
# This function is fine
def gridSwap():

    global gridCurrent
    global gridPrevious

    temp = gridCurrent
    gridCurrent = gridPrevious
    gridPrevious = temp
    return

def countLiveNeighbors( grid, rowIndex, columnIndex ):
    rows = len(grid)
    cols = len(grid[0])

    r = rowIndex
    c = columnIndex

    livecount = 0

    if grid[(r - 1) % rows][(c - 1) % cols] != 0:
        livecount += 1
    if grid[(r - 1) % rows][(c) % cols] != 0:
        livecount += 1
    if grid[(r - 1) % rows][(c + 1) % cols] != 0:
        livecount +=1
    if grid[(r) % rows][(c - 1) % cols] != 0:
        livecount += 1
    if grid[(r) % rows][(c + 1) % cols] != 0:
        livecount += 1
    if grid[(r + 1) % rows][(c - 1) % cols] != 0:
        livecount += 1
    if grid[(r + 1) % rows][(c) % cols] != 0:
        livecount += 1
    if grid[(r + 1) % rows][(c + 1) % cols] != 0:
        livecount += 1

    return livecount

def gridUpdate():
    global gridCurrent
    global gridPrevious

    # Here is where I am struggling
        for row in range(len(gridPrevious)):
            for column in range(len(gridPrevious[0])):
                live_neighbors = countLiveNeighbors(gridPrevious, row, column)

                if gridPrevious[row][column] == 1:
                # Any live cell with two or three live neighbors survives
                if live_neighbors == 2 or live_neighbors == 3:
                    gridCurrent[row][column] = 1
                else:
                    # All other live cells die
                    gridCurrent[row][column] = 0 
            
            elif gridPrevious[row][column] == 0:
                if live_neighbors == 3:
                    gridCurrent[row][column] = 1
                else:
                    gridCurrent[row][column] = 0

        return

gridPrevious = [[0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0],
                [0,1,1,1],
                [0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0]]


gridCurrent = [[0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0]]

gridUpdate()


print( "previous grid\n" )
print( gridToString( gridPrevious ), '\n' )

print( "current grid\n" )
print( gridToString( gridCurrent ), '\n' )

life_module.gridSwap()

print("My grid" \n")
print(gridToString(gridCurrent), '\n')




output:
Previous grid

++++
+OOO
++++
++++
++++


Current grid

++O+
++O+
++O+
++++
++++


My grid

++++
+OOO
++++
++++
++++
```

So my function for `gridUpdate` is not properly replacing the `gridCurrent` with `gridPrevious` I don't know if I've improperly called my `countLiveNeighbor` function or if my for loop is wrong. I'm not very good at coding and my teacher doesn't help us much when we have problems so sorry if its not very pythonic.

Edit: updated my code it now replaces the grid, although I still am confused on how to turn it horizontally like the current grid in this instance.

Comment: Don't replace the elements. Just use `gridCurrent = copy.deepcopy(gridPrevious)`

Comment: Typo: `for c in range(r)` should be `for c in range(col)`

Comment: Suggestion past the solution: parametrize your `gridUpdate` as well and avoid using globals.

Comment: Question out of cusiosity: is there a reason for not using other types than list, such as numpy array?

Comment: yes our teacher told us were not allowed to use numpy or pygame